# Links and Route not working

Tags: laravel

I am facing route problem I am using laravel 5.4 and xampp.
    I use this address 'localhost/project/laravel/public' to go to home page.
    When I click on any link in navigation region, I get object not found.
    After clicking,  address shows http://localhost/about

```
I edit home.blade.php as
href = "./" and "./about" By adding period
 problem solved to some extent
but when I am on another page
e.g  login page address is http://localhost/project/laravel/public/users/login
and if I want to go to contact page, again object not found message received
This time address is http://localhost/project/laravel/public/users/contact
I also tried href="{{ url('/contact')}}" in home.blade.php
The problem remains same.
    and
php artisan serve 
localhost:8000    gives 'unable to connect'
Please guide, thanks.
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is wrong, you aren't suppose to navigate to your project's public folder via the browser url... You just need to go to your laravel project folder and run Command prompt and type "**php artisan serve**". it will generate a url for you. entering that url on your browser will load your project properly and that way all links will work.

Comment: by using php artisan serve,  receive 
    Laravel development server started: <http://127.0.0.1:8000>. 
    But localhost:8000 address respond unable to connect

Comment: i advice you create a new project

Comment: I already tried new one but the same problem. Are there any settings to do which i don't know?

Comment: maybe you should follow the Laravel Document guide from scratch... maybe there's something missing or sth